# How do I use my raspberry pi?

Tags: pi-4

I just got a raspberry pi and I want to use it but I don't know how to use it. I tried to plug it into my windows CPU but it didn't work, so how do I use it. I want to code it with python by the way

Answer (score 3):

It will run by itself, it does not need to be connected to another computer although you can do that. It has a video connector, connect that to a monitor/TV, add a USB keyboard and mouse. Purchase a SD card with the operating system, a power supply (be sure it is the right voltage and supplies enough current) and away you go. Since this is probably just gobbledygook go to this link: https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/ The operating system is Linux or a variation thereof so you do not need to program in python, you can use most any language.

Answer (score 1):

See [What you will need](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/setup/)

There is extensive documentation https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/